# lightning-record-form failing when User doesn't have access to a field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, bug, summer19

There seems to be an issue with `lightning-record-form` in Summer'19. According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation) it's supposed to take care of field-level security and it used to (not showing a field to which User doesn't have access). Now if a certain profile has no READ access to a field included in `fields` attribute the component keeps showing spinner.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

That has probably nothing to do with my component but I will upload my code:

HTML

```
<template>

    <lightning-record-form object-api-name={objectApiName}
                           record-id={recordId}
                           columns={columns}
                           mode={mode}
                           onsuccess={handleSuccess}
                           fields={fieldsList}>
    </lightning-record-form>

</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class DBORecordForm extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    @api columns;
    @api mode = 'view';
    @api successMessage;
    @api fields;

    get fieldsList() {
        return this.fields ? this.fields.replace(/\s/g, '').split(',') : [];
    }

    handleSuccess() {
        if (this.successMessage) {
            const showToastEvt = new ShowToastEvent({
                title : this.successMessage,
                variant : 'success'
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(showToastEvt);
        }
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <description>Record Form</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="fields" type="String" label="Fields to display" required="true"
                description="List of fields separated by commas ( FirstName,LastName )"/>
            <property name="columns" type="Integer" default="2" label="Number of columns" min="1"/>
            <property name="mode" type="String" label="Form mode" datasource="view,edit,readonly" default="view" required="true"
                description="view/edit - can be switched between with edit/cancel/save. readonly - cannot change mode to edit"/>
            <property name="successMessage" type="String" label="Success message" description="If specified shows toast message."/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
    <masterLabel>Record Form</masterLabel>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I am having the same issue when testing in Aura component (`lightning:recordForm`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Salesforce bug. Issue should be resolved now. If you are still encountering similar problems contact Salesforce support.